# UITableViewDelegate disables itemselected

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make a simple change to a tableview for IOS. As my project is using Xamarin forms I use a custom renderer.

The changes I want to make is to close the keyboard is the table is scrolled, simple as that.

When I make the following changes it will work for my new scrolled override event but stops item (cell) selected from triggering (some of my cells navigate away from the page) and must be tapped.

```
public class CustomTableRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        var tableView = Control as UITableView;

        TableDelegate tableDelegate;
        tableDelegate = new TableDelegate();
        tableView.Delegate = tableDelegate;
    }
}

public class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
{
    #region Constructors
    public TableDelegate()
    {
    }

    public TableDelegate(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public TableDelegate(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Override Methods
    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(true);
        //base.Scrolled(scrollView);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have tried changing the `UITableViewDelegate` to `UITableViewController` but seems to cause more problems.

Adding in the override for all other methods calling base also does not seem to help. Not sure what I am missing.

Any idea why this is caused?

**Note:** If more information is needed please comment to let me know. Same with if the question is not clear. Comments would help.